# Poisson distribution question, tips needed!

Tags: probability, random-variables

A car dealership opens every day with a fresh stock of $A$ cars. Let $N$ be the r.v. corresponding to the number of purchases per day. Suppose $N$ is distributed according to the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=2$. What should $A$ be for the dealership to run out of cars to sell at most once every 10 days?

I have no clue how to begin to answer this question. How should I approach this problem? I'm not looking for a ready solution, but rather an explanation/tips on how to deal with this sort of problem. All I know is how the Poisson distribution looks like, and what the parameter means, but beyond that, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to interpret "at most once every $10$ days." With bad luck one could run out every day for a week, no matter how big $A$ is.

So we interpret "at most once every $10$ days" as meaning "with daily probability $\frac{1}{10}$."

So our stock should be such that $\Pr(N\le A) \ge 0.9$. Presumably we want the smallest such $A$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the interpretation that was bugging me indeed. Thanks for clearing it up for me.

Comment: You are welcome. Another interpretation would be that with at least some standard probability, like $0.95$, the number of times we run out in a randomly chosen $10$ days is $\le 1$. But since no confidence level was mentioned, I am reasonably confident that the simpler interpretation I gave is the intended one. Often in practical work, one main problem is giving a somewhat ambiguous verbal description a clear mathematical interpretation.